# what is the proper way to put a dot in a nested if

Tags: go, go-templates

I have the following code that fails to process in the template processor. I believe it is the dot in the if that is causing the parser to terminate early.

```
{{range Counter .first .last}}
     {{if eq . $.first}}
        first stuff here
     {{else}}
        some stuff here
     {{end}}
     and the remainder here
{{end}}
```

When I look at the resulting string it stops where the inner 'if' began. I'm thinking there might be an alias of the dot but have not found it. Although the DOC specifically says that the if will not change dot.

This sort of helps...

```
<eq . $.firstpid>: error calling eq: incompatible types for comparison
```

I was under the impression that the template system normalized the types. I'll have to look more closely into that.

Comment: The `{{if}}` action does not change the dot, but its enclosing `{{range}}` does. Which means `.first` in the `{{if}}` is not the same as the `.first` in the `{{range}}`. If dot above `{{range}}` is the passed param, you may use `$.first` and `$` inside `{{if}}`.

Comment: Are you checking the error return value from the template execute call?